# Cannot understand how to rotate text using drawText for qpainter

Tags: c++, qt

This is my code:

```
for (qint32 i = 0; i < leftF.size(); i++){
    QPointF p = leftF.at(i).screenpos;

    // Drawing the dot
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue));
    painter.drawEllipse(p,R,R);

    // Drawing a line
    painter.drawLine(p.x(),p.y(),p.x(),p.y()-lineH);

    // Drawing the text.
    painter.drawText(p.x(),p.y()-lineH,2*R,2*R,Qt::AlignCenter,QString::number(i));

    // Duration position.
    painter.rotate(-90);
    painter.drawText(p.x(),p.y()-lineH,4*R,2*R,Qt::AlignCenter,QString::number(leftF.at(i).dur));
    painter.rotate(90);

}
```

The problem is that I need the text in this line:

```
painter.drawText(p.x(),p.y()-lineH,4*R,2*R,Qt::AlignCenter,QString::number(leftF.at(i).dur));
```

to be prited at a 90 degree angle. However looking at this solution:

[How to rotate text for drawText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820428/how-to-rotate-text-for-drawtext)

What I do is what I should be doing, however it does not work as the text simply does not appear in the screen.

How I draw the rotated text at the point that I want? (in this case p.x(),p.y()-lineH)

Answer (score 4):

I've found it. In case anyone else topples this problem. The key is to translate the center of coordinates BEFORE the rotation. So in my case:

```
painter.save();
painter.translate(p.x()-10,p.y()+2*lineH);
painter.rotate(-90);
painter.drawText(0,0,4*R,2*R,Qt::AlignCenter,QString::number(rightF.at(i).dur));
painter.restore();
```

This worked like a charm!!