# Render a rotated text in QGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5, qglwidget

I want to display a rotated text in `QGLWidget`, Qt, C++, but I haven't been able to find a working code so far. Is it even possible to render a rotated text in **OpenGL**?

what I want is something like this Rotated Picture but every time I get the original one:

[image]

This is my code:

**Header file:**

```
#pragma once

#include "QGLWidget"
#include "QOpenGLFunctions_3_0"
#include "QOpenGLFunctions"
#include "QOpenGLShaderProgram"
#include "QOpenGLShader"
#include "QOpenGLBuffer"

class GLPlotter  : public  QOpenGLWidget,
                   protected  QOpenGLFunctions/*_3_0*/
{
public:
    GLPlotter(QWidget*  Parent = nullptr);

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();
    inline void Draw_Axis();
    inline void Draw_Text(QString  Text, double x,double y, double Angle);

private:
    void InitVertexShaderSource();
    void InitFragmentShaderSource();
    void InitVertexShader();
    void InitFragmentShader();
    void InitShaderProgram();

public:

protected:

private:
    QString m_VertexShaderSource;
    QString m_FragmentShaderSource;
    QString m_TextVertexShaderSource;
    QString m_TextFragmentShaderSource;

    QOpenGLShader* m_VertexShader;
    QOpenGLShader* m_FragmentShader;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram* m_ShaderProgram;

    double m_BoundaryLeft = -100.0;
    double m_BoundaryRight = +100.0;
    double m_BoundaryBottom = -100.0;
    double m_BoundaryTop = +100.0;
    double m_AxisLeft = -0.7;
    double m_AxisRight = +0.999;
    double m_AxisBottom = -0.8;
    double m_AxisTop = +0.999;
};
```

**`.cpp` file:**

```
#include "GLPlotter.h"

GLPlotter::GLPlotter(QWidget*  Parent ) : QOpenGLWidget(Parent){}

void GLPlotter::initializeGL()
{
    makeCurrent();

    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    InitShaderProgram();
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT);
}

void GLPlotter::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void GLPlotter::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    m_ShaderProgram->bind();

    Draw_Axis();
    Draw_Text("Hello", 0, 0, 30.0);

    m_ShaderProgram->release();
}


void GLPlotter::Draw_Axis()
{
    GLfloat Vertices[] =
    {
        static_cast<GLfloat>(m_AxisLeft)  , static_cast<GLfloat>(m_AxisBottom),
        static_cast<GLfloat>(m_AxisRight) , static_cast<GLfloat>(m_AxisBottom),
        static_cast<GLfloat>(m_AxisRight) , static_cast<GLfloat>(m_AxisTop),
        static_cast<GLfloat>(m_AxisLeft)  , static_cast<GLfloat>(m_AxisTop)
    };

    QOpenGLBuffer VBO(QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer);
    VBO.create();
    VBO.bind();
    VBO.allocate(Vertices, sizeof(Vertices));

    m_ShaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer("posAttr", GL_FLOAT, 0, 2 );
    m_ShaderProgram->enableAttributeArray("posAttr");

    QMatrix4x4 Matrix;
    Matrix.ortho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    m_ShaderProgram->setUniformValue("matrix", Matrix);
    m_ShaderProgram->setUniformValue("colorUniform", 255.0, 150, 0.0, 255.0);

    glLineWidth(4);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);

    m_ShaderProgram->disableAttributeArray("posAttr");
    VBO.release();
    VBO.destroy();
}

void GLPlotter::Draw_Text(QString Text, double x, double y, double Angle)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(Angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    renderText(x, y, 0.0, Text, QFont("Timew New Roman Bold Italic",20));
    glPopMatrix();
}

void GLPlotter::InitVertexShaderSource()
{
    m_VertexShaderSource = "attribute highp vec4 posAttr;\n"
                           "uniform highp mat4 matrix;\n"
                           "void main()"
                           "{"
                                "gl_Position = matrix * posAttr;\n"
                           "}\n";
}

void GLPlotter::InitFragmentShaderSource()
{
    m_FragmentShaderSource = "uniform lowp vec4 colorUniform;"
                             "void main()"
                             "{"
                                "gl_FragColor = colorUniform;\n"
                             "}";
}

void GLPlotter::InitVertexShader()
{
    m_VertexShader = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, this);
    m_VertexShader->compileSourceCode(m_VertexShaderSource);
}

void GLPlotter::InitFragmentShader()
{
    m_FragmentShader = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, this);
    m_FragmentShader->compileSourceCode(m_FragmentShaderSource);
}

void GLPlotter::InitShaderProgram()
{
    InitVertexShaderSource();
    InitFragmentShaderSource();
    InitVertexShader();
    InitFragmentShader();

    m_ShaderProgram = new QOpenGLShaderProgram(this);
    m_ShaderProgram->addShader(m_VertexShader);
    m_ShaderProgram->addShader(m_FragmentShader);
    m_ShaderProgram->link();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the right function? You might want to try `glRotatef(angle, x, y z)`. https://docs.gl/gl3/glRotate

Comment: I also tried glRotatef but its not working.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my question? Is everyone able to rotate the text in this way and is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe you should give more context and provide your entire source code. Does an error occur during compilation?

Comment: no there is no error

Comment: If you're that desperate for help please provide a [mcve] rather than incomplete snippets of code.

Comment: (***I haven't been able to find a working code so far***). Please detail how exactly is your code not working, how is your code currently behaving, and how do you want it to behave. Screenshots of the current and desired results would be helpful as well. Read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question), [C++ coding style standards](https://userweb.cs.txstate.edu/~v_m137/cs3358_fall2015/codingstyle.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820428/how-to-rotate-text-for-drawtext

Comment: Can you please clean up your code? Firstly, it's preferable to delete ``Draw_Axis()`` and the OpenGL objects relegated to it for this post (P.S. it's unhealthy to create a new VBO every ``paintGL``). Secondly, why are you using the legacy ``renderText``, and by extension, ``QGLWidget``? IMHO, it's better to use ``QOpenGLWidget``/``QPainter``. Actually, it may not be actually using fixed-function directives, thus why the fixed-function rotation functions have no effect.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I use qpainter in qopenglwidget before. It ruined my colors and opacities.